# Send dynamic parameter value with HTTP Request in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I'm aware of Correlation in Jmeter for passing dynamic value in JMeter, I usually create Regex Expression/CSS Selector Extractor for it and pass value as ${variable_name}. This works fine. Now recently i came up with scenario where value what i have to pass looks like below -

```
{"path":"Test123","sortExpression":"","startIndex":0,"maxRowNumber":10,"filterKeyWord":""}
```

I created one CSS Selector Extractor and fetch the value but when I'm passing like this , it does not recognize and fails. How can I pass this value ?

```
{"path":${createFolder},"sortExpression":"","startIndex":0,"maxRowNumber":10,"filterKeyWord":""}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to double quote String values in JSON

```
 {"path":"${createFolder}","sortExpression":"","startIndex":0,
```